# i am making a program of virtual assistant but i found this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyerror, sapi, pyttsx

Basically I am trying to make a program of virtual assistant in my windows 10 laptop but when I run the below script I found a very big error. and I am confused so i want a help for below code.

I am using version python 3.8 in windows 10. I am getting an error, `KeyError : 'sapi5'` and during handling of the above exception another exception occurs.
My code is importing pyttsx3. For solving this problem I found a solution which is similar for my problem and where
the person is giving a solution is talking about installing pypiwin32 module so that is have installed but still its doesn't  work . so please give the solution for my problem i just want the solution...

```
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
print(voices[1].id)
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    speak("bhanu is Iron man")
```

```
PS F:\Andi> python -u "f:\Andi\andi.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: 'sapi5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 3, in <module>
    from comtypes.gen import SpeechLib  # comtypes
ImportError: cannot import name 'SpeechLib' from 'comtypes.gen' (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 123, in WINFUNCTYPE
    return _win_functype_cache[(restype, argtypes, flags)]
KeyError: (<class 'ctypes.HRESULT'>, (<class 'comtypes.automation.tagVARIANT'>, <class 'ctypes.wintypes.LP_c_long'>), 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Andi\andi.py", line 3, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 6, in <module>
    engine = comtypes.client.CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 250, in CreateObject
    return _manage(obj, clsid, interface=interface)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 188, in _manage
    obj = GetBestInterface(obj)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 110, in GetBestInterface
    mod = GetModule(tlib)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 110, in GetModule
    mod = _CreateWrapper(tlib, pathname)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 184, in _CreateWrapper
    mod = _my_import(fullname)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 24, in _my_import
    return __import__(fullname, globals(), locals(), ['DUMMY'])
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\_C866CA3A_32F7_11D2_9602_00C04F8EE628_0_5_4.py", line 139, in <module>
    ISpeechBaseStream._methods_ = [
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 329, in __setattr__
    self._make_methods(value)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 698, in _make_methods
    prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(restype, *argtypes)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 125, in WINFUNCTYPE
    class WinFunctionType(_CFuncPtr):
TypeError: item 1 in _argtypes_ passes a union by value, which is unsupported.
```

this error i found while i'm trying to run my script...

Comment: From the documentation if you just run `pyttsx3.init()` then it will select the best driver available to you. If you are really determined to use sapi5 then the documentation says on windows it is `'SAPI5'` : https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html

Answer (score 0):

This helped me solve my problem. You may try it as well.

```
pip uninstall pyttsx3
pip install pyttsx3==2.6
```

#### Or

If you are using linux try 'espeak' TTS engine instead of 'sapi5'